# micro windows service inside ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC application serving our web pages and we also added few service routes for third party as currently we have only this MVC app wrapping on our database.
Now i need to implement MQTT message subscriber which should start the client to MQTT broker on start.

I was looking at Implementing a class which will implement connection initiation to MQTT broker and this method i can invoke from Application_start of MVC app.

Reason : why i want to do this having both microservice and MVC project is because this is very small project and we are in the initial phase of going live and don't want to scale the current system.Implementing a microservice will also need me to implement/create REST routes for microservice on recieving events from broker, which i guess i can handle if better implemented inside the MVC app directly on database repository.

I want to know the loops/problems my MVC application can became victim of by following this approach.

So far my code looks like this

global.asax.cs file

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            MQTTSubscriber.StartMQTTSubscriber();
        }
```

MQTTSubscriber.StartMQTTSubscriber() is where i am going to handle connection to MQTT broker.

Few more doubts i have 
1)Do i really need windows service to establish connection to broker, i mean MVC 5 application_start will be triggered every time MVC application domain will start, be it through IIS or Visual Studio and i can write connection establish logic inside MQTTSubscriber.StartMQTTSubscriber() like following

```
// create client instance 
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse(MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS)); 

// register to message received 
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived; 

string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
client.Connect(clientId); 

// subscribe to the topic "/home/temperature" with QoS 2 
client.Subscribe(new string[] { "/home/temperature" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

2)If this is do-able way , please inform me things i need to handle/take care for this work-around.

Any help/suggestions will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: or i can implement windows project in the same solution with business/repository layer shared with the windows service as well to handle all the event listener logic down to data  layer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can start the micro service inside asp.net app. Since C# is not a functional language but you can use Application start to do initial one time startup for any app in .net